# Interval of validity of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Please help me with parts (c) and (d).

Part (c) says that we need to find the interval of validity, do I need to put x=0 and then check for values of y? I already did that and got y = 0, +2, -2. So, that means that the interval of validity is [0,0], [-2,0], and [0,2] but I can see that the ODE has a vertical tangent at y= +2/sqrt(3), and -2/sqrt(3). That basically means that the above intervals I mentioned is not valid.

So, what should I do??

Also, for part (d), I dont have any idea what to do. Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine for a moment the related equation

$$x'(y) = \frac{3y^2-4}{3x^2}$$

At the place where the previous function had a vertical tangent, this one has a critical point. Let's take the second derivative to find out what kind of critical point it is:

$$x''(y) = \frac{3x^2(6y)-(3y^2-4)6xx'}{9x^4} = \pm\frac{2|y|}{x^2} \neq 0$$

at the critical points. The exact value is not important, only the fact that it is not $0$. A differentiable function with a local min or a max is not invertible since the inverse would fail the vertical line test.

This means that the specific curve we want that contains $(0,0)$ only goes up to the $x$ value that gives the vertical tangent. Solving:

$$x^3 = y(y^2-4) \implies x = \mp \frac{2\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$$

and your interval of convergence is on

$$\left[-\frac{2\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{2\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\right]$$

which contains $0$. The instructor had you draw a slope field to avoid this chain of reasoning because it only makes rigorous what the drawing makes obvious.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, for part (d), am I supposed to take random values of x and calculate y and then plot (x,y) on the direction field or I need to do something else?

Comment: @AshisJana all you need to do is trace over the slope field you have. Some of the slopes should be on the curve you want, so let the slopes guide your trace up to the vertical tangent.

Comment: Can you please tell me which equation I am supposed to use? is it the solution equation?

Comment: @AshisJana what are you talking about? Did you or did you not draw the slope field? If you did, then literally just trace over the slope field starting at $(0,0)$. If not, then draw the darn slope field. There is no equation!

Comment: Can you please explain me why you took x'(y) = (3y^2-4)/3x^2 ?

Comment: @AshisJana I'm not sure what you would have me explain. I had an idea, I wrote it down, and it happened to work. If you want me to explain why it works, that only tells me you didn't read my post. Or if you are confused about something else, ask a more specific question.

Comment: do u think x''(y) is correct? How are you getting 6xx' at the end. As far as i knw, I think its supposed to be only 6x. I took a look at your solution, its correct n i understand that but I am wondering why you wrote that at the end.

Comment: @AshisJana because at that moment $x$ was the dependent variable, and $y$ was the independent variable. The derivative was with respect to $y$, hence $x'$ by chain rule.